# Argument of type 'string | number | string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number |

Tags: jquery

I wrote ajQuery code to determine height and width and click functinality. Code is as given below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      console.log("Jquery is working!");
      adjustBar();
      $(window).on('resize', function() {
        adjustBar();
      })
    $('#height').on('input change', function() {
        var height = $(this).val();
        if (height >= 30) {
        var leftOffset = (Math.tan(45 * (Math.PI / 180)) * (height / 2) + 3) * -1;
        $('.steps').css('height', height).css('line-height', height + "px").css('left', leftOffset + "px");
        adjustBar();
      }
    });
    $('.steps').on('click', function() {
      $('.steps').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    })
  });
  function adjustBar() {
      var items = $('.steps').length;
      var elHeight = $('.steps').height() / 2; //Division by 2 because each pseudo which is skewed is only 50% of its parent.
      var skewOffset = Math.tan(45 * (Math.PI / 180)) * elHeight;
      var reduction = skewOffset + ((items - 1) * 4);
      var leftOffset = $('.steps').css('left').replace('px', '');
      var factor = leftOffset * (-1) - 2;
      $('.steps').css({
        'width': '-webkit-calc((100% + 4px - ' + reduction + 'px)/' + items + ')'
      }); // 4px for borders on either side
      $('.steps:first-child, .steps:last-child').css({
        'width': '-webkit-calc((100% + 4px - ' + reduction + 'px)/' + items + ' + ' + factor + 'px)'
      }); // 26px because to make up for the left offset. Size of last-child is also increased to avoid the skewed area on right being shown  
      $('.steps span').css('padding-left', (skewOffset + 15) + "px");
      $('.steps:first-child span, .steps:last-child span').css({
        'width': '-webkit-calc(100% - ' + factor + 'px)'
      });
    }
```

When I run that code, I get these errors:

> error TS2362: The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.
>   event-viewer/event-viewer.component.ts(34,35): error TS2345: Argument of type 'string | number | string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | ((this: HTMLElement, index: number, value: string) => string | number | void)'.
>     Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | ((this: HTMLElement, index: number, value: string) => string | number | void)'.
>       Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
>   event-viewer/event-viewer.component.ts(49,20): error TS2362: The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.

It seems that `height`, `width` and `leftoffset` are considered as String, but they should be numerical values which are calculated by position of element in web page. How can I fix those errors?

Comment: Did you try casting the values to Number? For example `var height = Number($(this).val());`

Comment: Ah! this casting didn't come to my mind, thank you :)

Comment: Did it solve the problem? I can then make it as an answer.

Comment: Yeah, it solved the problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should convert the string value to a number.
You can use: `var height = Number($(this).val());`